# Get Records using Firebase 3 - Javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to pull all comments created by user using the uid. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

```
var commentsRef = firebase.database().ref('comments');
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    commentsRef.orderByChild("owner/uid").equalTo(user.uid).on("child_added", function (snap) {
        console.log(snap)
    });
```

Comment: You have two levels of push IDs in your path and your query only accounts for one. That is, the data is `comments/-KZj.../-KZm.../owner/uid` and your query is looking for `comments/-KZj.../owner/uid`. Without restructuring your database, you cannot perform the query you are attempting.

Comment: The best solution is to add a `sortKey` that you can use to sort data.